# Table: Cases braces being overlapped by white when alternating colors used

Tags: tables, formatting, cases

I would like to use the cases environment in a table with alternating row colours. Here is some example code.

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        1 & 7\\
        2 & \(\displaystyle
            \begin{cases}
                a & \quad b\\
                c & \quad d
            \end{cases}\)\\
        3 & 4
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this results in the braces being overlapped by white. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Note that if you simply code `\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{ }`, you have no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following solution fulfill your expectation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  %to use direct sum symbol
\usepackage{mathtools}              % <---
\usepackage{cellspace}              % <---
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}   % <---
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}% <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{cSc}
        1 & 7               \\ 
        2 & \(
            \begin{dcases}   % <---
                a & \quad b\\
                c & \quad d
            \end{dcases}\)  \\ 
        3 & 4
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked great! Two follow up questions
1. What is the difference between dcases and cases?
2. The braces are very close to reaching into other rows - if I want a bit more space between the top and bottom of the cells what can I do? I tried increasing the cellspace limits but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @BaroqueFreak,  (i) content in `dcases` is in `\displaystyle` while not `cases`, (ii) if you like to have more space, increase numbers in`\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt} \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}` to desired vertical space.